# sed command to change part of a line

Tags: shell

I guess I could write a little python script to do this, but I am trying to learn how to do this kind of stuff using just the shell, since I think it makes more sense.

Basically I have something like this:

database.txt:

```
line1|tag1
line2|tag1
line3|tag2
line4|tag1
```

lines_to_change.txt:

```
line1
line4
```

what_i_want.txt:

```
line1|tag2
line2|tag1
line3|tag2
line4|tag2
```

So, basically, what I want is to, for each line in the `lines_to_change.txt` file to change the tag of that line from `tag1` to `tag2`. I was told this is a job for the command line `sed`, but can't find my way arround the man documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cat lines_to_change.txt | xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/{}|tag1/{}|tag2/g' database.txt
```

The result will be saved into `database.txt` itself

Comment: Note that `-i` is deprecated by GNU `xargs` and not supported by the BSD version. Use `-I '{}'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will toggle between tag1 and tag2.

(So if it's tag1, it changes it to tag2, and if it's tag2, it changes it to tag1.)  It hinges around an intermediate tag, "tag3" (doesn't matter what you call this) but it allows you to toggle without knowing the existing tag state.  file2.txt has your tokens, and file1.txt is your database file (the -i command adds in-place):

```
cat file2.txt | xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/{}|tag1/{}|tag3/gp;s/{}|tag2/{}|tag1/gp;s/{}|tag3/{}|tag2/gp' file1.txt
```

One thing I implore you to commit to memory is the ability to pass the output of one command into the input of another via the following string:

```
| xargs -I '{}'
```

as this will make you an extremely powerful command line user.

EDIT:

If you simply want to change all tag1 to tag2, here you go:

```
cat file2.txt | xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/{}|tag1/{}|tag2/gp' file1.txt
```

Comment: for what I have understood from your comment, your answer toggles between tag1 and tag2. What I want is simply to change all `tag1` to `tag2` from the lines in `lines_to_change.txt`. If you would consider editing you answer.

Answer (score 0):

First use sed on your lines_to_change.txt file to create another sed script:

```
sed 's;.*;/&/s/tag1/tag2/;' lines_to_change.txt > lines_to_change.sed
```

Then use that new command file to edit your original:

```
sed -f lines_to_change.sed database.txt > what_i_want.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } 
    $1 in a{ $2 = "tag2" } 1' FS=\| OFS=\| lines_to_change.txt input.txt
```